Why are my numpy array elements being cast to lists?
import numpy as np

ar1 = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]])
ar2 = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]]])

print(ar1)
print(ar2)

When I run this the second array prints out with a list() casting around the elements.  Here are the print() results:
[[[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]]
[[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]]]
[[list([1, 2, 3]) list([4, 5, 6])]
[list([1, 2, 3, 4]) list([4, 5, 6, 7])]]
Do the one dimensional arrays all need to be the same length for some reason?  Do I have to cast them as arrays if they aren't the same length?
I'm using Python version 3.8.10.

What numpy version?  Older versions made ar2 an object dtype - that's list-like and able to hold objects with varying sizes. Newer versions warn or even raise an error if you don't specify the dtype=object.  numpy can't make numeric arrays from lists that differ in length.

ar1.shape is (2,2,3), right?  ar2.shape is (2,2).  It can't be (2,2, ??)!

There are many subleties in this (it depends, indeed, on numpy version). But short and a bit simplistic answer is "yes, you need constant size along each axis". Numpy's point is to work on hyper-cuboids (bunch of data, accessed through strides arr[x1,x2,x3,...] = base[x1*stride1+x2*stride2+x3*stride3+...]). There are some way to handle other data, but you need to ask yourself why using numpy on data where it would be inefficient? Numpy is not a generic data structure library. It is a way to vectorize numerical computation. It is fast when it can do that.

In a newer numpy version, your code produces an error:
In [157]: ar1 = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]])
     ...: ar2 = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]]])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[157], line 2
      1 ar1 = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]])
----> 2 ar2 = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]]])

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (2, 2) + inhomogeneous part.

Trying again but with explicit dtype:
In [158]: ar2 = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]]],dtype=object)

In [159]: ar2
Out[159]: 
array([[list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6])],
       [list([1, 2, 3, 4]), list([4, 5, 6, 7])]], dtype=object)

Note the shapes.  One is 3d with integer elements, the other 2d with list elements:
In [160]: ar1.shape, ar2.shape
Out[160]: ((2, 2, 3), (2, 2))

With inconsistent list lengths it can't make a 3d numeric array.  With object dtype, this array is much more like a list, containing references to lists stored elsewhere in memory.  Math on such an array is hit-of-miss, and not as fast as on ar1.
edit
When creating ar2, you provide a nested list.  numpy makes a 2d array, where each element is one of the inner most lists.  There's no casting; they are lists in the input object, and remain so in the result. In ar1 it is able to fill a 3d array with numeric values from the input nested list.
